# Is a hold on a ticket sufficient proof of flight reservation for French visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, paperwork, schengen-visas

I've applied for a student short stay visa for France (on an Indian passport) and the local consulate required the following for the application : Copy of personal return flights reservation with confirmed dates.

I didn't want to book tickets by paying before applying since I applied around 10 working days before my travel and there is every chance the visa may not be processed in time. So what I did was to go to Yatra.com, an Indian website which allows one to hold a flight reservation for 24 hours for free. There I booked tickets (Qatar Airways) and placed a hold without paying. I got a PNR and using it, I printed a ticket from Qatar's site and gave it as my flight reservation proof for the application. But the catch is since I didn't pay in 24 hours, the hold expired and if someone now searches with the PNR on Qatar's site, there will be no such booking. Is this a problem? Will the consulate actually check this? I don't think I'm expected to book flights when the visa approval is uncertain and hence don't see why this should be a problem. But will it be?

Comment: How did it work out?

Comment: It didn't, the consulate required fresh tickets. Fortunately, the lab I'm visiting was kind enough to book the tickets for me on request. I got the visa a week after that, just hours before my flight.

Comment: so the consulate realized the ticket is no longer valid and asked for a new one? Could you post your experience as an answer to the question - it would be of great help to future travelers.

Answer (score 3):

Source: [comment of the OP](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68187/is-a-hold-on-a-ticket-sufficient-proof-of-flight-reservation-for-french-visa#comment149440_68187) after interaction with the consulate.

An (expired) hold on a ticket is not enough, the consulate does require a good ticket.

Comment: It also depends on embassy, evrn if it is Schengen. Italian in Doha says just bring a schedule of flights and proof that you can afford it. German says fake/just booking can get you banned..